# Apache default charset doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, charset

I am trying to set default charset to ISO-8859-1, so I added the line below into httpd.conf.

```
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-9
```

and I can see that value when I query it with

```
root@server [/]# curl -A "Mozilla/4.0" http://localhost -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2012 22:28:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Aug 2012 21:17:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 111
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

However, I can't get the same results for virtual hosts and there is no additional definitions for any other charset.

```
root@server [/]# file temp.php
temp.php: ISO-8859 text

root@server [/]# cat temp.php    
Cesária Évora

root@server [/]# curl -A "Mozilla/4.0" http://somedomain/temp.php -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2012 22:28:31 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Do you have any idea ? Please let me know if you have a clue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `charset` attribute in `Content-Type` for PHP is handled by `php.ini`.

Add `default_charset = iso-8859-1` to your php.ini or use `ini_set( "default_charset", "iso-8859-1" )` in your `temp.php`.
http://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.default-charset